# want to access my Samba shared folder from outside my Local network

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, samba, samba4

On Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 I installed Samba server and its working perfect within my Local network .
Now , I need to access the file outside my network , for that I opened port 137, 138, 139 and 445 on ubuntu and on my Router as well .Even after this I am unable to access samba by Public IP .
Please suggest me .
Thanks .

Comment: Hi , Please give me some idea regarding my issue .

Answer (score 3):

This is not the answer you want but...

1) Close those ports

Samba shares over the internet is very insecure. Samba isn't designed to secure over the internet.

2) setup a VPN. its more complicated but much more secure. Look into l2tp vpn.